# Is it better to have the day off of work for Friday prayers or just some time off of work?

Tags: work, jumuah

Just wondering about this from a cross-cultural sensitivity sort of angle. Many Christians and Jews have a normal work-week in the USA with Saturday and Sundays off which coincides well with their religious observances.

I've seen businesses make provisions for male Muslim coworkers who have Friday prayer times,  but is it better, or would it be better, if the company would allow them to organize their entire week around Friday observances, or is a few hours for prayer sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no Islamic requirement or even recommendation for the Friday to be taken as a day of rest. Inre the Friday prayers, the Qur'an states (emphasis mine):

> <sup>9</sup> O you who have believed, when [the adhan] is called for the prayer on the day of Jumu'ah [Friday], then proceed to the remembrance of Allah **and leave trade**. That is better for you, if you only knew.
> <sup>10</sup> And when the prayer has been concluded, disperse within the land and **seek from the bounty of Allah**, and remember Allah often that you may succeed.
> — [Al-Jumu'ah 9-10](https://legacy.quran.com/62/9-10)

This strongly suggests the opposite, that the Friday prayer is performed *during* the regular work day; observers are expected to "leave trade" (i.e. abandon work) when the call is made, and then to go and "seek from the bounty of Allah" (i.e. go back to work) when it is over.